# Retag request X and x11

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Please merge tags [x](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/x), [x11](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/x11) <s>and [xorg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xorg)</s> <sup>See Daniel Beck’s comment</sup>.  They seem to refer to the same thing.

Comment: `x` is the X Window system protocol, `x11` its current major release (since the late 80s), and `xorg` a specific implementation (as opposed to e.g. [xfree86](http://superuser.com/search?q=xfree86)). See e.g. [here](http://superuser.com/a/145039/22317). While there's probably no practical difference between `x` and `x11`, there is one between spec and implementation.

Comment: Again, stop using a useless meta tag like [tag:what-irks-me]